# Properties of immersions and embeddings

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Definition 1: $f \in C^{\infty}(M,N)$ is called immersion iff $\forall x \in M: \operatorname{Ker} d_x f = 0$.

Definition 2: $f \in C^{\infty}(M,N)$ is called embedding iff it is immersion and topological embedding (homeomorphism on image).

I have to prove following:

1. Every immersion is a local embedding
2. Image of embedding is a submanifold
3. Embedding is a diffeomorphism between $M$ and $f(M)$.

This theorem is left without a proof because it is called "easy". But i would like to know the proof, maybe i can read it somewhere?

What i understand is that (3) easily follows from inverse function theorem. Also, (1) easily follows from (3).

And one more thing disturbs me: $M$ can have non-empty boundary. Does that call some difficulties?

Comment: For 2., be careful how a submanifold is defined. It can be that the image of M is not a [neat submanifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neat_submanifold). It is something called "embedded submanifold". Some related notes on your question are in Chapter 2 of Kosinski's Differential Manifold, for example. Yes, implicite function theorem is needed.

Comment: Thanks. I will now try to prove that it will be an embedded submanifold. It shouldn't be hard i suppose.